# How to implement GMail Android App listview animation?

Tags: android, email, listview, animation, gmail

In the new update of the Gmail App, there is a very cool animation implemented. If I click a mail from the inbox listview, the item's text slides upto the top and becomes heading of the next page where the entire mail is shown, when I press back, the whole email collapses to the very same spot (i.e at very same index in the inbox listview). It looks pretty cool, I haven't been able to figure out how are they doing it, any idea?

Comment: Code and solution are too broad. You should post some code so far or any implementation you try to do... here is not to get full implementations. Try to follow this official google video and have a better clue idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA

Comment: This is probably Fragment Transition from Lollipop. You can start with Activity Transition, the lighter version of Fragment Transition. https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

Answer (score 0):

It's called sharedAnimation transitions, the title is a shared view among the fragments/activities. check this out: 
https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/share-element-transition-between-recycler-view-and-fragment-8ce5084fd7a2